# Automatic coloring of numbers according to size

Tags: tables, color

Scientific talks have their own culture, reporting the results, typically for me, in a table of the following form

```
1.7333    1.6472    1.5418    1.4682    1.5740
1.1525    1.2878    1.2652    1.3511    1.5102
1.2181    1.1500    1.2220    1.2425    1.5699
0.9786    1.1051    1.1472    1.3096    1.6757
0.9569    0.9190    1.0433    1.2924    1.4867
```

There is clearly a(n almost perfectly) monotonic pattern for rows and columns.
Now for the naked eye, this is not the most quick way of capturing informing.

I would like numbers that bigger in absolute value, to appear differently (either green vs red or light vs dark) than smaller numbers, such that the pattern becomes clear instantly.

Is there a way of programming this in LaTeX?

Comment: Scientific talks should not contain numeric tables at all. True, many do, but only because most scientific talks are abysmally bad. Use charts, and only display the *relevant* information. Minimize.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Related Question: [LaTeX Tables: Cell value color based on its sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174234/latex-tables-cell-value-color-based-on-its-sign).

Answer (score 15):

You can use [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to process an entry based on the numeric value. Below I have defined the `R` column type to apply a percent of black based on the numerical value.

[image]

### Notes:

- One could adapt this to apply different colors based on the size of the number and perhaps that would yield even better results.  For instance, use a different color based on which quartile the number is in (<25% use gray, 25-50% use brown, 50-75% use black, >75 use red).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{collcell}

% This selects the amount of color to use
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.5}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.8}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \textcolor{black!\PercentColor}{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{R R R R R}
1.7333 & 1.6472 & 1.5418 & 1.4682 & 1.5740 \\
1.1525 & 1.2878 & 1.2652 & 1.3511 & 1.5102 \\
1.2181 & 1.1500 & 1.2220 & 1.2425 & 1.5699 \\
0.9786 & 1.1051 & 1.1472 & 1.3096 & 1.6757 \\
0.9569 & 0.9190 & 1.0433 & 1.2924 & 1.4867 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I suggest the package [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable). With the following code you test if the contents of the cell is lower than a specified `\bordervalue` (I took 1.4). Based on the result the number will be printed in green or red.

At the moment the input isn't tested if it is a number or not. So be careful.

```
   postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={%
    \pgfmathparse{int(less(#1,\bordervalue))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
       \color{red} #1
    \else
       \color{green!60!black} #1
    \fi
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}%
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\def\bordervalue{1.4}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[row sep=\\,col sep=&,assume math mode=false,
   postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={%
    \pgfmathparse{int(less(#1,\bordervalue))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
       \color{red} #1
    \else
       \color{green!60!black} #1
    \fi
}},]
{%
1.7333    & 1.6472    & 1.5418    & 1.4682    & 1.5740  \\
1.1525    & 1.2878    & 1.2652    & 1.3511    & 1.5102  \\
1.2181    & 1.1500    & 1.2220    & 1.2425    & 1.5699  \\
0.9786    & 1.1051    & 1.1472    & 1.3096    & 1.6757  \\
0.9569    & 0.9190    & 1.0433    & 1.2924    & 1.4867  \\
}
\end{document}
```