# pgfplotstable: Conditional post-processing of cell content on a per-column basis

Tags: conditionals, pgfplotstable

I am trying to add an asterisk to the content of certain cells depending on the cell's content (essentially, adding a marker for significant p-values) but I am having trouble trying to do so on a per-column rather than per-table basis. I adapted an answer to a similar question that [colours cells based on their numerical value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57334/14210) but that seems to only work when applied to the whole table. If I try to apply the style to a single column (uncommenting the two lines in the example below), I get a `Missing number, treated as zero.` error that seems to expect a number after the closing square bracket instead of the file name.

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
%  columns/a/.style={ % Uncommenting causes #1 to be empty
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(less(#1,\bordervalue))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           $^*$
        \else
           $^\dagger$
        \fi
      },
    },
%  },
]{mwe.dat}
```

[image: Applying postproc cell content/.style to the whole table]

This seems to be because, once I wrap the `postproc cell content` style in a `column` style, it no longer has access to the contents of that cell. `#1`, `@unprocessed cell content`, `@cell content after rowcol styles`, and `@preprocessed cell content` all equate to nothing, while `@cell content` always equates to the content of the very last cell of the whole table.

```
% #1 is empty when wrapped in a column style
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{#1},
    },
  },
]{mwe.dat}
```

[image: #1 is empty in postproc cell content when wrapped in a column style]

```
% @cell content contains the last cell of the whole table
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}},
    },
  },
]{mwe.dat}
```

[image: @cell content contains the last cell of the whole table]

Results are similar when using `.code` instead of `.style`:

```
% Using .code, @cell content still only contains the very last cell of the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.code={%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}}%
    },
  },
]{mwe.dat}
```

[image: Using .code instead of .style, @cell content still only contains the very last cell of the table.]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.dat}
a         b         c         d         e
1.7333    1.6472    1.5418    1.4682    1.5740  
1.1525    1.2878    1.2652    1.3511    1.5102  
1.2181    1.1500    1.2220    1.2425    1.5699  
0.9786    1.1051    1.1472    1.3096    1.6757  
0.9569    0.9190    1.0433    1.2924    1.4867  
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
}

\begin{document}

\def\bordervalue{1.4}
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
%  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(less(#1,\bordervalue))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           $^*$
        \else
           $^\dagger$
        \fi
      },
    },
%  },
]{mwe.dat}

\bigskip 

\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}},
    },
  },
]{mwe.dat}

\bigskip 

\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
  columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={%
      \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}}%
      \fi
    },
  },
]{mwe.dat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `##1` instead of `#1` in your first approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.dat}
a         b         c         d         e
1.7333    1.6472    1.5418    1.4682    1.5740  
1.1525    1.2878    1.2652    1.3511    1.5102  
1.2181    1.1500    1.2220    1.2425    1.5699  
0.9786    1.1051    1.1472    1.3096    1.6757  
0.9569    0.9190    1.0433    1.2924    1.4867  
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
}

\begin{document}

\def\bordervalue{1.4}
\pgfplotstabletypeset [assume math mode=false,
columns/a/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,\bordervalue))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           $^*$
        \else
           $^\dagger$
        \fi
      },
    },
},
]{mwe.dat}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It had to be something very simple ... Would you mind explaining what the difference between ``#1`` and ``##1`` is in this case and/or in general?

Comment: It allows you to access the arguments of a nested macro: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument