# post-process cell content in one column based on another column

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to do something quite similar to this post:

[pgfplotstable: Conditional post-processing of cell content on a per-column basis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100458/pgfplotstable-conditional-post-processing-of-cell-content-on-a-per-column-basis)

However, I'd like to post-process the column based on the content from another column. For example, I want to add a `*` to the `coefficient` column if the corresponding `t-value` is greater than 2.

In the table, usually I only report the `coefficient` and `standard error`, not the `t-value`. I'd like to post-process the `coefficient`columns based on values from `coefficient/standard error`.

Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.dat}
coefficient {standard error} 
-.0159375    .008852
-.0107286   .0091658
.0042201   .0089453
.0108719   .0038041
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{test1.dat}\results
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\thisrow{coefficient}/\thisrow{standard error}}]{t-value}{\results}

\def\bordervalue{2}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={coefficient, standard error, t-value},
columns/t-value/.style={ 
    %preproc/expr = {100*##1},
    postproc cell content/.style={
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{%
    \pgfmathparse{int(greater(##1,\bordervalue))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
       $^*$
    \fi
    },
    },
},
]\results
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I put the `*` to the `coefficient` column so that I don't need to report the `t-value`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider [spreadtab](http://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a tricky way:

```
columns/coefficient/.style={
postproc cell content/.append code={%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{t-value}\of{\results}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TvalueTest}{\pgfplotsretval > \bordervalue ? 1 : 0}%
\ifthenelse{\TvalueTest = 1}% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$}{*{}^*$}} }% then
{}% else
}},
```

BTW: I simplificated your method for adding a star in the `t-value` column:
`\pgfmathparse{##1 > \bordervalue ? "^*" : ""}\pgfmathresult`

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.dat}
coefficient {standard error} 
-.0159375    .008852
-.0107286   .0091658
.0042201   .0089453
.0108719   .0038041
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bordervalue{2}

\pgfplotstableread[]{test1.dat}\results
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\thisrow{coefficient}/\thisrow{standard error}}]{t-value}{\results}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={coefficient, standard error, t-value},
columns/t-value/.style={numeric type,  
postproc cell content/.style={
/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$}{
\pgfmathparse{##1 > \bordervalue ? "^*" : ""}\pgfmathresult$  % New
},},
},
% New:
columns/coefficient/.style={
postproc cell content/.append code={%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{t-value}\of{\results}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TvalueTest}{\pgfplotsretval > \bordervalue ? 1 : 0}%
\ifthenelse{\TvalueTest = 1}% if 
{\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{pink}$}{*{}^*$}}}% then
{}% else
}},
]\results
\end{document}
```