# Huge table/matrix with colored boxes

Tags: tables, plot, csv

I have a huge CSV file with about 25.5k records that (structurally) looks like the sample below. In essence, I want to display the values of the columns U,V,W,X,Y,Z of each row as a colored box. The color of each box should represent its value, i.e. the value dictates what color along some gradient is to be drawn. E.g.: The larger the value, the darker the box.

Now, there are a few things that I'd like to highlight using colors:

- Group names should be written to the left of the item names, turned 90 degrees, once per group. (items are sorted by group)
- The background colors of groups (and their items) should alternate
- Within a group, item's background colors should alternate
- There is a column `special`, which when `TRUE`/`1` should change the item's bg-color(map) to a special/alternative color for the current group's bg-color. In total there are two possible group bg-colors, and four possible item bg-colors.
- Also, when `special` is `TRUE`/`1`, the value color should be picked from a special/alternative gradient. In total there are two gradients/colormaps to pick from.
- The labels/columns U,V,W,X,Y,Z at the bottom should also be colored with alternating bg-colors.
- the labels/columns at the bottom should at a 90 degree angle, and aligned to the right (or top, in absolute terms).

Since the number of rows is so large, and I want the complete drawing to fit on a single page, the rows will need to be *quite* thin. (The columns should fit without compressing).
Never the less, I do want the group and item text in there, because the dedicated reader should be able to zoom into the digital version of the final document, while regular/paper readers can obtain sufficient information from the alternating group colors.

**Sadly, I have no idea how to start solving this problem.**

*conceptual rendering (done in a spreadsheet):*
This is roughly what I hope to achieve. (Minus the grid lines.)

[image]

*sample csv:*

```
group,item,special,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
a,a1,0,0.2,,0.2,,,
a,a2,0,,0.1,,,0.4,1
a,a3,0,,0.5,,,,
a,a4*,1,0.1,,0.8,,,
a,a5*,1,,,,,0.5,0.5
a,a6,0,,,,0.3,,
b,b1,0,,0.1,,,,
b,b2,0,0.6,,,0.4,,
b,b3*,1,,,0.4,,,
c,c1*,1,,,,,,0.1
c,c2*,1,,0.2,,,0.3,0.2
c,c3,0,,,0.7,,,
c,c4,0,,0.6,,0.3,,
c,c5,0,,,,,,0.7
...
```

columns explained:

- group: String
- item: String
- special: Boolean
- U,V,W,X,Y,Z: real number in the range 0..1

Comment: Since just want the table in a **single page** or image, and with no text in each cell. I imagine it kind of like: [data visualization](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/). If I were you, I would be using python and matplotlib to just produce a single image (and `\includegraphics` if you want in a latex). See something like that [heat map example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set). The important matplotlib command for this task is [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Comment: If you are okay with going down the `python` road, then I can help you more with that. But it really feels like you need some programming anyway because you have to convert that CSV into latex.

Comment: I'm okay with python, *if* I can use the exact same colors + colormaps I'm using in other pgfplots already. The `\includegraphics` route is fine by me.

Comment: I also would like to add that the final result should be a PDF with vectors; nothing rasterized.

Comment: Then I think it's best to use `python` read CSV and output some pgfplot code then. (no need to use matplotlib)

Comment: You could use the [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell). An example that might help you get started: [Automatic coloring of numbers according to size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/automatic-coloring-of-numbers-according-to-size).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**:
After the OP stressed again that he want to use existing `colormap` from `pgfplots`, I think it might be better for him to use [`\pgfplotstabletypeset`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz) with a bit of preprocessing of csv.

However, if you're like me who is more comfortable with `tikz/pgf` and `python`,
then the answer below should provide more flexibility. The one thing I'm not satisfied with this answer is that the table will not auto-adjust if group label is too long.

---

**in.csv**:

```
group,item,special,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
a,a1,0,0.2,,0.2,,,
a,a2,0,,0.1,,,0.4,1
a,a3,0,,0.5,,,,
a,a4*,1,0.1,,0.8,,,
a,a5*,1,,,,,0.5,0.5
a,a6,0,,,,0.3,,
b,b1,0,,0.1,,,,
b,b2,0,0.6,,,0.4,,
b,b3*,1,,,0.4,,,
c,c1*,1,,,,,,0.1
c,c2*,1,,0.2,,,0.3,0.2
c,c3,0,,,0.7,,,
c,c4,0,,0.6,,0.3,,
c,c5,0,,,,,,0.7
```

**main.py**:

```
import csv

# read csv into matrix
with open('in.csv') as csvf:
    f = csv.reader(csvf)
    a = [r for r in f]

# separate the header
header = a[0]
a = a[1:]

# separate by group
def sep_group(a):
    cur_group = None
    groups = []
    for r in a:
        # new group?
        if cur_group != r[0]:
            groups.append([r])
            cur_group = r[0]
        else:
            groups[-1].append(r)
    return groups
a = sep_group(a)

# calculating shade based on value in csv
def shade(x):
    return 0 if x == '' else str(int(float(x)*100))

# output while traversing data
with open('out.tex','w') as f:
    f.write('\\matrix [nodes={cell}] {\n')
    for gi,g in enumerate(a):
        for ri,r in enumerate(g):
            # empty node to place group label upon later
            f.write('\\node{}{} {{}}; &\n'.format(
                ' [alias=g{}begin]'.format(gi) if ri == 0 else '',
                ' [alias=g{}end]'.format(gi) if ri == len(g)-1 else ''))
            # item label
            f.write('\\node [group{}{}/item{},minimum width=3em] {{{}}}; &\n'.format(gi%2,'/special' if r[2] == '1' else '',ri%2,r[1]))
            # cells in the row
            f.write(' &\n'.join(
                '\\node [fill={}!{}] {{}};'.format('Emerald' if r[2]=='1' else 'black',shade(c))
                for c in r[3:]))
            f.write(' \\\\\n')
    # footer
    f.write('&')
    for ci in range(len(g[0])-3):
        f.write('&\n\\node [footer{},rotate=90] {{{}}}; '.format(ci%2,chr(ci+ord('U'))))
    f.write('\\\\\n')
    # end matrix
    f.write('};\n')
    # now overlay the group labels
    for gi,g in enumerate(a):
        f.write('\\node (last) [inner sep=0,group{},fit=(g{}begin) (g{}end)] {{}};\n'.format(gi%2,gi,gi))
        f.write('\\node [rotate=90,anchor=mid] at (last) {{{}}};\n'.format(g[0][0]))
```

running main.py produces **out.tex**:

```
\matrix [nodes={cell}] {
\node [alias=g0begin] {}; &
\node [group0/item0,minimum width=3em] {a1}; &
\node [fill=black!20] {}; &
\node [fill=black!0] {}; &
\node [fill=black!20] {}; &
\node [fill=black!0] {}; &
\node [fill=black!0] {}; &
\node [fill=black!0] {}; \\
\node {}; &
\node [group0/item1,minimum width=3em] {a2}; &
\node [fill=black!0] {}; &
...
```

out.tex is used in **main.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    cell/.style={outer sep=0pt, minimum size=2em},
    group0/.style={fill=blue!30},
    group0/.cd,
        item0/.style={fill=blue!30},
        item1/.style={fill=blue!60},
        special/.cd,
            item0/.style={fill=Emerald!30},
            item1/.style={fill=Emerald!60},
    %
    /tikz/.cd,
    group1/.style={fill=Dandelion!30},
    group1/.cd,
        item0/.style={fill=Dandelion!30},
        item1/.style={fill=Dandelion!60},
        special/.cd,
            item0/.style={fill=LimeGreen!30},
            item1/.style={fill=LimeGreen!30},
    %
    /tikz/.cd,
    footer0/.style={fill=YellowGreen!60},
    footer1/.style={fill=RedOrange!60},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \input{out.tex}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**result**:

[image: output v3]

This shows the matrix being painted in shades according to the values in CSV file. I try to use as similar color to OP as possible.

Comment: edits to add header and row labels to this answer are welcomed, as I might be too busy to modify this.

Comment: I also haven't alternate the color between adjacent rows as well.

Comment: updated, only 1 thing left: group label

Comment: Looks good so far. Does it work with pgfplots's `colormap`s as well? N.B.: I only need two color(map)s to pick from for the value cells. For the item column, there should be four, though. I updated the question to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Actually, I have not used `pgfplots` before, but since `pgfplots`'s based on `tikz/pgf` which is what I am using here. I assumed that it would work. Can you send a link to documentation/example of `colormap` to me?

Comment: I am adding the group label, but you raised a good point `colormap` which should be checked before I get any deeper into this. I'm waiting.

Comment: found `colormap` documentation, http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf. Seeing those examples, it should work together. I'm experimenting.

Comment: actually, this question is very relevant: [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

Comment: The only thing missing from `\pgfplotstabletypeset` (as I see in those questions) is how to do multirow cell for group label. the complex coloring scheme in this question can be achieved by defining custom `colormap` with some discontinuous points to account for 'special & normal' coloring with values in csv being preprocessed (maybe by python) accordingly. This seem like a better solution than mine, but it has gone outside my comfort zone. So, I'm going to leave this where it is now.

Comment: Since this answer is still incomplete I will not accept it yet. However, to recognize your effort I have awarded you the bounty.

Comment: @derabbink I got time to come back and finished this off. What do you think?