# Table vs Plot: How to print table of values, with colors representing values

Tags: tables, plot

In an effort to collect knowledge that will ultimately allow me to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152251/huge-table-matrix-with-colored-boxes), I am seeking a way to generate a table where numeric values are plotted as cell-filling colors. The color should represent the number.
N.B.: I am not trying to repost the question I mentioned above. Here I am asking for a way to approach merely a subset of that question.

A rendering of my MWE below:
[image: plot as a table]

So far, I have been trying to achieve this using pgfplots (inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153971/31877)), but there are some drawbacks in the measuring department:
I'd have to do all the math by hand, in order to make sure all rows and columns align nicely (see MWE).
Additionally, styling tick labels with alternating styles will be tough, as a PGFplot is not entirely built to do that. And on top of that, adding meta-labels in order to group tick labels (see [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152251/huge-table-matrix-with-colored-boxes)) is probably going to be impossible.

In a nutshell, the approach I have so far (using PGFplots) is not ideal, since what I want is to draw a table. But then, tables don't have these powerful ways of representing numeric values as colors, a.f.a.i.k.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
yitem,xitem,val
a,X,0.1
a,Z,0.3
b,Y,0.5
b,Z,0.6
c,Y,0.8
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=data,
    ytick=data,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    symbolic x coords={X,Y,Z},
    symbolic y coords={a,b,c},
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style=transparent,
    y tick label style={
        inner sep=0,
        font=\tiny,
    },
    x tick label style={
        inner sep=0,
        font=\tiny,
        rotate=90,
        anchor=east,
    },
    enlarge x limits={abs=1mm},
    enlarge y limits={abs=1mm},
    x=2mm,
    y=2mm,
]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    mark size=1mm,
    only marks,
    scatter,
    mark options={outer sep=0},
    scatter/use mapped color={fill=mapped color,draw opacity=0},
    point meta=explicit,
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    x=xitem,
    y=yitem,
    meta expr=\thisrow{val},
] {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz), [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz), and [matlab2tikz imagesc TikZ/pgfplots equivalent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/matlab2tikz-imagesc-tikz-pgfplots-equivalent) for some approaches to similar problems.

Comment: Would you consider using a plot? If yes, you can do this with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Is this question still current? Or is the list of @Jake's links sufficient?

Comment: And I am a little bit confused. It sounds as if you want to have table (sounds a lot like @Jake's links). Or do you want a more systematic way to do this as plot, i.e. like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287006/1537 ? In this case, it might be a duplicate.

Comment: Imho, the question "how can I group tick sections with pgfplots" (or should it be "... with pgfplotstable?") should become a separate question as it seems to be beyond the scope of this question. The remaining aspects could be duplicates of the linked questions/answers.

Comment: This question is so old, I'm not sure I remember all the details any more. However, I did manage to come up with a solution based on @Jake's links. I'll see if I can write up an answer explaining how I did this soon.

Comment: One year seems not to be soon enough ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP states he's solved it using the comments, albeit he's not provided a full answer in more than a year