# render table completely

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create my class routine in latex, but it renders partially:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
            & 9.00-9.45 & 9.50-10.35 & 10.40-11.25 & 11.30-12.15 & 12.20-1.05 & 1.05-1.30 & 1.30-2.15 & 2.30-3.05 & 3.10-3.55 & 4.00-4.45 \\
        Sun &           & 717        & 717         &             &            & *         &           &           &           &           \\
        Mon & 715       & 715        & 711         & 711         & 712        & *         & 712       & 719       & 719       &           \\
        Tue &           &            &             &             &            & *         &           & 716       & 716       &           \\
        Wed &           & 711        & 713         & 714         & 714        & *         & 717       & 717       & 719       & 719       \\
        Thu &           &            &             &             &            & *         & Thesis    & Thesis    & Thesis    & Thesis    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried different points in documentclass, even 6 point but it doesn't fit in the pdf.

I even tried `adjustbox`, but for some unknown reason texwork doesn't recognize it and can't even install it. So is there anyway I can render it completely ?

Current render :

[image]

Comment: article class has 10pt,11pt and 12pt options it does not take arbitrary lengths like 6pt, you can make the table smaller by using a smaller font such as `\footnotesize`

Comment: Do you want just this table or is it a part of a document? There are different strategies to include such large tables. If this is just one single table without any text use class `standalone`.

Comment: Also transposing the table might be an idea (making the days into columns and the dates into rows).

Comment: Can you change (decrease)  the margins of your document? An alternative yould be rotating the table to a landscape orientation. You could also introduce linebreaks in the column headers.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad  were you able to select any of the responses to your question

Comment: @jsbibra actually i encountered some problem with my texworks, here is the [log](https://pastebin.com/tpKY9V75), so...

Answer (score 6):

Here are four MWEs that fit within their margins.

I used [scrartcl](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) from [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) to have more sensible margins. You can achieve the same by loading [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Also, consider allowing some more vertical space (air) in the tabular. Load the [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package and add the following two commands to the preamble:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
```

See the effect in example 3.

*Example 1*: I reduced the font size to small. [scrartcl](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) standard is 11 pt. Also, I defined a `\thead` macro for the ten headings. The text is set in a narrow `p`-column, and aligned at the right margin. In addition, I aligned all the column at the right, except the first and sixth.

At last, I loaded [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), and set a `\midrule` after the heading and removed the side bearings at the left and right side of the tabular, see the `@{}` in the definition of the tabular.

*Example 2*: Here, I used tabular* instead of tabular. I set `\tabcolsep` to 0, and let `tabular*` calculate the space between columns. In addition, I reduce the width of the heading cells untill all had line breaks.

*Example 3*:  This is probably the simplest solution and what I recommend for you: Load the excellent [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) package and let LaTeX do all the calculation. I reduced `\tabcolsep` slightly more, removed the side bearings and reduced font size as in the other examples. Be aware that the first column is an ordinary `l`-column. Thereafter, I have 10 right aligned `R`-columns:

*Example 4*: Inspired by Bernhard, but slightly different. Due to how `\rowcolor` and `\columncolor` work, I removed side bearing by setting `\tabcolsep` to 0 and added space between columns using very narrow columns (defined as new column type `N`). The `T`-column uses a feature described in the [dcolumn manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/dcolumn.pdf).

**Example 1 – using tabular**

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs}

\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{p{\dimexpr((\linewidth/11)-2\tabcolsep)\relax}}{\raggedleft #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrcrrrrr@{}}
   & \thead{9.00--9.45} & \thead{9.50--10.35} & \thead{10.40--11.25}
   & \thead{11.30--12.15} & \thead{12.20--1.05} & \thead{1.05--1.30}
   & \thead{1.30--2.15} & \thead{2.30--3.05} & \thead{3.10--3.55}
   & \thead{4.00-4.45} \\ \midrule
Sun &     & 717 & 717 &     &     & * &        &        &        &       \\
Mon & 715 & 715 & 711 & 711 & 712 & * &   712  &   719  &   719  &       \\
Tue &     &     &     &     &     & * &        &   716  &   716  &       \\
Wed &     & 711 & 713 & 714 & 714 & * &   717  &   717  &   719  &   719  \\
Thu &     &     &     &     &     & * & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis \\  
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – using tabular***

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs}

\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth/13)}}{\raggedleft #1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small\centering
\begin{tabular*}\linewidth{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{10}{r}}
   & \thead{9.00--9.45} & \thead{9.50--10.35} & \thead{10.40--11.25}
   & \thead{11.30--12.15} & \thead{12.20--1.05} & \thead{1.05--1.30}
   & \thead{1.30--2.15} & \thead{2.30--3.05} & \thead{3.10--3.55}
   & \thead{4.00-4.45} \\ \midrule
Sun &     & 717 & 717 &     &     & * &        &        &        &       \\
Mon & 715 & 715 & 711 & 711 & 712 & * &   712  &   719  &   719  &       \\
Tue &     &     &     &     &     & * &        &   716  &   716  &       \\
Wed &     & 711 & 713 & 714 & 714 & * &   717  &   717  &   719  &   719  \\
Thu &     &     &     &     &     & * & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis \\  
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 3 – [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs, tabulary, array}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
\begin{tabulary}\linewidth{@{}l*{10}{R}@{}}
    & 9.00--9.45\, & 9.50--10.35\,
    & 10.40--11.25\, & 11.30--12.15\,
    & 12.20--1.05\, & 1.05--1.30\,
    & 1.30--2.15\, & 2.30--3.05\,
    & 3.10--3.55\, & 4.00-4.45\, \\ \midrule
Sun &     & 717 & 717 &     &     & * &        &        &        &       \\
Mon & 715 & 715 & 711 & 711 & 712 & * &   712  &   719  &   719  &       \\
Tue &     &     &     &     &     & * &        &   716  &   716  &       \\
Wed &     & 711 & 713 & 714 & 714 & * &   717  &   717  &   719  &   719  \\
Thu &     &     &     &     &     & * & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis \\  
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 4 – tabular, dcolumn and [xcolor](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs, dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{N}{wc{1em}}
\newcolumntype{T}{D{-}{-}{5,5}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{table}
\centering\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}}TN*{5}{cN}@{}}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}
            && Sunday && Monday && Tueday && Wednesday && Thursday\\
9.00-9.45   &&        &&   715  &&        &&           &&         \\
9.50-10.35  &&   717  &&   715  &&        &&    711    &&         \\
10.40-11.25 &&   717  &&   711  &&        &&    713    &&         \\
11.30-12.15 &&        &&   711  &&        &&    714    &&         \\
12.20-1.05  &&        &&   712  &&        &&    714    &&         \\
1.05-1.30   &&    *   &&    *   &&    *   &&     *     &&    *    \\
1.30-2.15   &&        &&   712  &&        &&    717    && Thesis  \\
2.30-3.05   &&        &&   719  &&   716  &&    717    && Thesis  \\
3.10-3.55   &&        &&   719  &&   716  &&    719    && Thesis  \\
4.00-4.45   &&        &&        &&        &&    719    && Thesis  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I propose one of these solutions, in addition to using a sideways table: 
either load `geometry` to have default smaller margins, and use the small font size, or swap rows and columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\rowhead}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\,#1\,}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\bgroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.2 pt}
\small
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\columncolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}}l@{\quad}*{10}{l}@{}}
\cellcolor{white} & \thead{9.00--9.45} & \thead{9.50--10.35} & {10.40--11.25} & \thead{11.30--12.15} & \thead{12.20--1.05} & \thead{1.05--1.30} & \thead{1.30--2.15} & \thead{2.30--3.05} & \thead{3.10--3.55} & \thead{4.00--4.45 }\\
\cmidrule{2-11}
        \rowhead{Sun} & & 717 & 717 & & & * & & & & \\
\addlinespace
        \rowhead{Mon} & 715 & 715 & 711 & 711 & 712 & * & 712 & 719 & 719 & \\
\addlinespace
        \rowhead{Tue} & & & & & & * & & 716 & 716 & \\
\addlinespace
        \rowhead{Wed} & & 711 & 713 & 714 & 714 & * & 717 & 717 & 719 & 719 \\
\addlinespace
        \rowhead{Thu} & & & & & & * & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis & Thesis
    \end{tabular}
\egroup
\vspace{1cm}


\newcolumntype{T}[1]{D{-}{\,\textendash\,}{#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{WhiteSmoke}\small}T{4}*{5}{l} }
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{white}} & Sun & Mon & Tue &Wed & Thu \\
\addlinespace
 9.00-9.45 & & 715 \\
9.50-10.35 & 717 & 715 & & 711 \\
10.40-11.25 & 717 & 711 & & 713 \\
11.30-12.15 & & 711 & & 714 \\
12.20-1.05 & & 712 & & 714 \\
1.05-1.30 & * & * & * & * & * \\
1.30-2.15 & & 712 & & 717 & Thesis \\
2.30-3.05 & & 719 & 716 & 717 & Thesis \\
3.10-3.55 & & 719 & 716 & 719 & Thesis \\
4.00-4.45 & & & & 719 & Thesis \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Bernhard The natural direction to read a tabular is from top left to bottom right, i.e. it is the row that has the focus. The interest for a reader of a time schedule will be the day, not the time slot of each day in the week. Therefore, if you change the direction of the table, you should also add some reading aid, f. ex. vertical rules (yes!), a light column (vertical) or similar.

Comment: @Sveinung: Do you prefer this layout for the secod version (with a simpler code)?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

With some prettifying of table header column converted to light grey with the help of

> \rowcolor{gray!30}

First column converted to light grey with the help of

> {\columncolor{gray!30}}l

Center column converted to red with the help of

> {\columncolor{red}}c

Digits having `7` as the start are highlighted with light blue

```
> \makeatletter \newcommand*{\minuscellcolor}{}
> \def\minuscellcolor\ignorespaces{%   % \ignorespaces not really
> needed, because \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces  
> \@ifnextchar7{\cellcolor{blue!20}}{}% } %
> \newcolumntype{L}{>{\minuscellcolor}l}
> \newcolumntype{C}{>{\minuscellcolor}c} %
> \newcolumntype{R}{>{\minuscellcolor}r} \makeatother
```

Gives a neater perspective of the data visually(I think)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#1}\scriptsize}c%
<{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\minuscellcolor}{}
\def\minuscellcolor\ignorespaces{%
  % \ignorespaces not really needed, because \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces
  \@ifnextchar7{\cellcolor{blue!20}}{}%
}
% \newcolumntype{L}{>{\minuscellcolor}l}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\minuscellcolor}c}
% \newcolumntype{R}{>{\minuscellcolor}r}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}  
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}}lCCCCC>{\columncolor{red}}cCCCC}  
    \toprule  \rowcolor{gray!30}
    \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{9.00-9.45}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{9.50-10.35}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{10.40-11.25}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{11.30-12.15 }
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{12.20-1.05 }
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{1.05-1.30}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{1.30-2.15}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{2.30-3.05}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{3.10-3.55}
      & \multicolumn{1}{R{2cm}}{4.00-4.45}\\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-1} \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4} 
    \cmidrule(rl){5-5} \cmidrule(rl){6-6} \cmidrule(rl){7-7} \cmidrule(rl){8-8} 
    \cmidrule(rl){9-9} \cmidrule(rl){10-10}   \cmidrule(rl){11-11}   
    Sun &     & 717 & 717 &     &     & * &     &    &    &   \\  
    Mon & 715 & 715 & 711 & 711 & 712 & * & 712 & 719&719 &   \\  
    Tue &     &     &     &     &     & * &     & 716&716 &   \\  
    Wed &     & 713 & 714 & 714 & 714 & * & 717 & 717&719 &719\\  
    Thu &     &     &     &     &     & * & \#\   & \#\  & \#\ & \#\  \\
    \#\ = Thesis&&&&&&&&&&\\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Courtesy @GonzaloMedina---

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14742/197451

and @GuilhermeZanotelli---

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329740/197451

Comment: You might want to replace `2cm` with `1.5cm` for a smaller distance between the toprule and the rotated text. Also, you might want to correct the cmidrules. Their width is not uniform.

Comment: why the downvote--reasons

Answer (score 1):

Two more example, both with reduced page margins:

- use `tabularx`, `[table]{xcolor}` packages and `\small` font size

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

- use `sidewaystable`, `tabularx` and `[table]{xcolor}` packages

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \small 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{white}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | *{10}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} }
    \cline{2-11}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & 9.00 - 9.45 & 9.50 - 10.35 & 10.40 - 11.25 & 11.30 - 12.15 & 12.20 - 1.05
    & 1.05 - 1.30 & 1.30 - 2.15  & 2.30 - 3.05   & 3.10 - 3.55   & 4.00 - 4.45 \\
   \hline
Sun &           & 717        & 717         &             &            
    & *         &            &             &             &           \\
Mon & 715       & 715        & 711         & 711         & 712       
    & *         & 712        & 719         & 719         &           \\
Tue &           &            &             &             &            
    & *         &            & 716         & 716         &           \\
Wed &           & 711        & 713         & 714         & 714        
    & *         & 717        & 717         & 719         & 719       \\
Thu &           &            &             &             &           
    & *         & Thesis     & Thesis      & Thesis      & Thesis   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{white}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | *{10}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} }
    \cline{2-11}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & 9.00 - 9.45 & 9.50 - 10.35 & 10.40 - 11.25 & 11.30 - 12.15 & 12.20 - 1.05
    & 1.05 - 1.30 & 1.30 - 2.15  & 2.30 - 3.05   & 3.10 - 3.55   & 4.00 - 4.45 \\
    \hline
Sun &           & 717        & 717         &             &
    & *         &            &             &             &           \\
Mon & 715       & 715        & 711         & 711         & 712
    & *         & 712        & 719         & 719         &           \\
Tue &           &            &             &             &
    & *         &            & 716         & 716         &           \\
Wed &           & 711        & 713         & 714         & 714
    & *         & 717        & 717         & 719         & 719       \\
Thu &           &            &             &             &
    & *         & Thesis     & Thesis      & Thesis      & Thesis   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```