# How to interpolate two colors in a cell?

Tags: tables, color, environments

I just want to fill a cell with a two colors range like a heatmap, see the figure bellow.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you really want a table like that you showed? The color hurts ...  Can you please add an compilable code resulting in the shown table?

Comment: I agree the colour is very painful. Have you seen this post? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174234/latex-tables-cell-value-color-based-on-its-sign-conditional-cell-color

Comment: Anyway, look up fadings in the PGF manual.  Page 348 has a useful example.

Comment: If you're going to use saturated red-purple-blue, it should be against white -- either white text on a coloured background, or just colour the text. With the approach shown here you could mix it with some white

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question appealed to me: how do you automatically colour the entries of a table based on the values in the cells? That is, how do we make the  not-so-random table

```
\begin{tabular}{ *7H }
-1.0 & -0.9 & -0.8 & -0.7 & -0.6 & -0.5 & -0.4 \\
-0.3 & -0.2 & -0.1 &  0.0 &  0.1 &  0.2 &  0.3 \\
 0.4 &  0.5 &  0.6 &  0.7 &  0.8 &  0.9 &  1.0 \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Min
   \tikz{\shade[left color=blue,right color=red] 
          (current page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,12pt);}
    Max}
\end{tabular}
```

produce the following?

[image]

[The OP is perhaps mainly asking about drawing a gradient shading, but as  John Kormylo says in the comments (and shown above), this is easy to do using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz).]

In answering this I assumed that these matrices have entries between `-1` and `1` -- it is easy to change the code below to work for other domains. To automatically assign a background colour to each cell based on the value of the entry I first use the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package to define a new column type

```
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\Heat}r<{\endcollectcell}}
```

In turn, the `H` column type uses the [collcell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package to apply the the command `\Heat` to each cell entry. The `\Heat` macro first maps the cell entry to an integer between `0` and `100` using [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

```
\pgfmathparse{int(50+50*#1)}% map number in [-1,1] to [0,100]
```

This number is then used to set the background colour of the cell with `\cellcolor{red!\pgfmathresult!blue}` -- although,  in practice a little expansion hackery is needed here. With these definitions in place the code above does what I wanted.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\Heat}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand\Heat[1]{% \Heat{number in the interval [-1,1]}
    \pgfmathparse{int(50+50*#1)}% map number in [-1,1] to [0,100]
    \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{red!\pgfmathresult!blue}}%
    \HeatCell$#1$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *7H }
-1.0 & -0.9 & -0.8 & -0.7 & -0.6 & -0.5 & -0.4 \\
-0.3 & -0.2 & -0.1 &  0.0 &  0.1 &  0.2 &  0.3 \\
 0.4 &  0.5 &  0.6 &  0.7 &  0.8 &  0.9 &  1.0 \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Min
   \tikz{\shade [left color=blue ,right color=red]
         (current page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,12pt);}
    Max}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This said, the choice of colours makes the table very garish and unpleasant to look at. A first improvement would be to make the text colour white, which we can do by changing `\Heat` to:

```
\newcommand\Heat[1]{% \Heat{number in the interval [-1,1]}
    \pgfmathparse{int(50+50*#1)}% map number in [-1,1] to [0,100]
    \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{red!\pgfmathresult!blue}}%
    \HeatCell\textcolor{white}{$#1$}%
}
```

This produces:

[image]

We could instead change the colours to `Yellow1` and `SpringGreen3` (using the `x11names` option to [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)), to get:

[image]

**Edit**

Just for fun here's the same code but with a [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) interface for setting the colours and the min/max values via `\Heatset{min colour=blue, max colour=red}` etc. There is also a slider `\Heatset{slider= <width> }` for the gradient bar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% set up pgfkeys for controlling heat specifications
\pgfkeys{/heat/.is family, /heat,
    min colour/.initial = Yellow1,
    max colour/.initial = SpringGreen3,
    text colour/.initial = black,
    min color/.style = {min colour=#1},% for our friends who can't spell
    max color/.style = {max colour=#1},
    text color/.style = {text colour=#1},
    min/.initial = -1,
    max/.initial = 1,
    slider/.code={%
       \tikz{\shade[left color=\HVal{min colour},%
                    right color=\HVal{max colour}]%
          (current page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,12pt);
       }%
    }%
}
\newcommand\Heatset[1]{\pgfkeys{/heat, #1}}
\newcommand\HVal[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/heat/#1}}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\Heat}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\Heat[1]{% \Heat{number in the interval [min, max] }
  \pgfmathparse{int(100*(#1-\HVal{min})/(\HVal{max}-\HVal{min}))}% map number to [0,100]
  \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{\HVal{max colour}!\pgfmathresult!\HVal{min colour}}}%
  \HeatCell\textcolor{\HVal{text colour}}{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *7H }
-1.0 & -0.9 & -0.8 & -0.7 & -0.6 & -0.5 & -0.4 \\
-0.3 & -0.2 & -0.1 &  0.0 &  0.1 &  0.2 &  0.3 \\
 0.4 &  0.5 &  0.6 &  0.7 &  0.8 &  0.9 &  1.0 \\
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{Min \Heatset{slider=5.5} Max}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\noindent
\Heatset{max colour=red, min colour=blue, min=0, max=100, text colour=white}
\verb|\Heatset{max colour=red, min colour=blue, min=0, max=100, text colour=white}|
\begin{tabular}{ *7H }
 10 &  90 &  80 &  70 &  60 &  50 &  40 \\
 30 &  20 &  10 &  00 &  10 &  20 &  30 \\
 40 &  50 &  60 &  70 &  80 &  90 &  10 \\
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{Min \Heatset{slider=3.0} Max}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: I have only one problem with your solution...everyone *knows* that Min is blue and Max is red, as in the temperature analogy!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Well, clearly *not* everyone! :) I'll succumb to peer-group pressure and change it.

Comment: +1, `\edef\HeatCell` rather than `\xdef\HeatCell` works.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks. Changed. I'm too heavy handed :)

Comment: the `\HeatCell` defintion line lacks an `%` at the end. The space token introduced is not ignored in tabular.

Comment: @jfbu Hmm, I was assuming that spaces were ignored since the tabular is aligning the column to the right but it seems you're right and the cells above are slightly pushed to the right. Thanks. I'll fix.

Comment: The reason is that the action of `\ignorespaces` token inserted by LaTeX's kernel code does not extend to the other side of the `\edef`, which acts like a "barrier". (by the way this is independent of alignment of column cells)

Comment: actually, with `collcell` loaded, it has a `\collcell@beforeuser` which is hardcoded in style file to be macro with content `\ignorespaces` (except if package option `verb`). Anyway, the expansion recomposes the standard LaTeX setting with an `\ignorespaces` first and an `\unskip` last.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, thank you so much. There is one more thing, do you know how can I align the rectangle so the bottom part is at the same level at the cell, if you look closer you will see it is even above the level of letters (e.g. min, max)

Comment: @Avenger Using `(current page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,12pt)` in the shade command works better. Instead of hard coding the `12pt` could put `\def\lineheight{\the\baselineskip}` after `\begin{document}` and then use `(curreant page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,\baselineskip)`. I've justed updated the answer -- but I have only fixed the last image.