# Coloring the characters of a ligature, without breaking the ligature

Tags: pdftex, ligatures

The TeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
ffi
\end{document}
```

produces the following ligature when compiled to PDF:

[image: [image]]

Note that *ffi* is represented by a single special character.

However, when I try to color each character in a different color, the characters won't translated to a ligature anymore. For example, when I type

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{f}\textcolor{blue}{f}\textcolor{green}{i}
\end{document}
```

the produced PDF looks as follows:

[image]

Note that *ffi* is now represented by three individual characters.

Is there any possibility to color the characters without breaking ligatures apart, i.e.: to produce a ligature like in the first example but with colored characters?

Comment: A ligature is, by definition, a *single* glyph.

Comment: not really: you could convert the outline of the ligature back to paths (pstricks can do that forexample) and then colour the parts separately. or colour the ligature character but then clip to show each part, doing that three times

Comment: @egreg: Good point :-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492129/can-you-write-a-macro-such-that-each-character-will-be-the-next-color-of-the-rai may help you...

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `\llap` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{f}\textcolor{blue}{f}\textcolor{green}{i}

\textcolor{red}{ffi}\llap{\textcolor{blue}{fi}}\llap{\textcolor{green}{i}}
\end{document}
```

It's not perfect (little discrepancy in the "i", why?, perhaps the PDF viewer?), but it's easy.

[image]