# How to fill a cell in a table with two colors like a heatmap?

Tags: tables, color, gradient

I'm new to LaTeX. This is a similar question to [How to interpolate two colors in a cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401370/how-to-interpolate-two-colors-in-a-cell/)

The relative codes from the answer is helpful @user30471:
The H column type uses the `collcell` package to apply the command \Heat to each cell entry. However, I have over 18 columns on my table. I tried to use  `\begin{tabular}{ cc *18H }` to create heatmap tables as that question, but might the maximum number of columns allowed in `\Heat` is 9. I copied the `\Heat` code from @user30471. And my table code is:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Summary of power ($\times1000$)... }
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}
\begin{tabular}{r rrrrrr rrrrrr rrrrrr}
\toprule
     & \multicolumn{6}{c}{minp1} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{minp2} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{treep}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-7}\cmidrule(l){8-13}\cmidrule(l){14-19}
    % \begin{sidewaystable}[h]

    $\tau$ & i & ii & iii & iv & v & vi & i & ii & iii & iv & v & vi & i & ii & iii & iv & v & vi \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{18}{c}{0\% censoring}\\
    % \begin{sidewaystable}[h]
    -0.8 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100\\ 
    -0.6 & 97 & 98 & 98 & 97 & 98 & 98 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100\\
    -0.4 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 90 & 92 & 92 & 91 & 91 & 92 & 87 & 88 & 88 & 84 & 88 & 88\\
    -0.2 & 22 & 22 & 22 & 22 & 22 & 23 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 31 & 30 & 33 & 26 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 24 & 27\\
    0 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 6\\
    0.2 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 30 & 31 & 33 & 32 & 33 & 28 & 27 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 27\\
    0.4 & 39 & 39 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 94 & 95 & 95 & 95 & 95 & 95 & 85 & 89 & 87 & 87 & 88 & 87\\
    0.6 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 82 & 81 & 81 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100\\
    0.8 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100\\    
    [1ex]
    & \multicolumn{18}{c}{25\% censoring}\\
    -0.8 \\
    % -0.7 \\
    -0.6 \\
    % -0.5 \\
    -0.4 \\
    % -0.3 \\
    -0.2 \\
    % -0.1 \\
    0 \\
    0.2 \\
    0.4 \\
    0.6 \\
    0.8 \\
    [1ex]
    & \multicolumn{18}{c}{50\% censoring}\\
    -0.8 \\
    -0.6 \\
    -0.4 \\
    -0.3 \\
    -0.2 \\
    -0.1 \\
    0 \\
    0.2 \\
    0.4 \\
    0.6 \\
    0.8 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab: 1cut}
\end{table}
```

The figure is here: [image] I'd like to get the figure like this: [image] But it can only be up to 9 columns by:

```
  \Heatset{min=0,   % maximum value
           max=100,   % minimum value
           max colour=Gray0, % colour at maximum
           min colour=Snow1,      % colour at minimum
  }
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Summary of power ($\times1000$)... }
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}
\begin{tabular}{cc * 9H}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{minp1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{minp2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{treep}\\
\cmidrule(l){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}\cmidrule(l){7-9}
& &\multicolumn1c{i}&\multicolumn1c{ii}&\multicolumn1c{iii}&\multicolumn1c{iv}&\multicolumn1c{v}&\multicolumn1c{vi}&\multicolumn1c{i}&\multicolumn1c{ii}&\multicolumn1c{iii}\\
& -0.8& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100\\
& -0.6& 97 & 98 & 98 & 97 & 98 & 98 & 100& 100& 100\\
& -0.4& 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 76 & 90 & 90& 90\\
& -0.2& 22 & 22 & 22 & 22 & 22 & 23 & 29& 29& 29 \\
\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\textsf{$\tau$}}}
& 0& 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4& 4& 4\\
& 0.2& 13 & 14 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 30& 30& 30\\\
& 0.4& 39 & 39 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 94 & 94 & 94\\
& 0.6& 80 & 81 & 82 & 82 & 81 & 81 & 100 & 100& 100\\
& 0.8& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100& 100\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How to fill in heatmap colors in `\begin{tabular}{r rrrrrr rrrrrr rrrrrr}` by modifying my code? Or other ways to create a similar table?

Comment: Review - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401404/247020

Comment: I think it is not heat map, a gradient something, the word "heat map" is confusing, specially it seems like the data has a relation with the heat map. Not a issue of your question :-). But might get a dupe-nuke from these: tex.stackexchange.com/q/174998/247020. Did you mean the gradients you would find in MS word or heatmaps as red=higher, blue=lower?

Comment: You should put a complete working example (with 9 columns). The, we could try to see whether it works for a larger number of columns and, if not, try to solve the problem. At this time, we don't have your MWE and that's why it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

When the column is greater than 9, it should be `\begin{tabular}{cc * {10}H}` not `\begin{tabular}{cc * 10H}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.