# How can I draw a vertical Line In Matrix and add Arrows?

Tags: amsmath

Here is a pic of this.
[image]

[image]Is there away to type this thing out?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33519. The answer below can also be found there.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat How about Adding Arrows behind this?

Comment: Add `\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3}` after the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{} rrr|rrr @{\,}}
 1 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
-2 &  0 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 1 & -1 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about adding arrows behind Matrices?

Comment: @kile, just ad `\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3}` (as is done in @Schrödinger'scat's answer). It require to load `amsmath` package. See edited answer.

Comment: Might be an idea to use `@{} rrr| rrr @{}` as that then corresponds to the fence spacings used by the ams matrix envs

Comment: @daleif, you are right. I will correct code asap ...

Answer (score 2):

This is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33523), which borrows from [this post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/), and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522747), which uses [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174359). The purpose is to align the minus signs and numbers nicely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33523
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\def\CheckMinus\ignorespaces{\@ifnextchar-{}{\phantom{-}}}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{J}{>{\CheckMinus}l}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}[JJJ|JJJ]
 1 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
-2 &  0 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 1 & -1 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
  \end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}[c][{rrr|rrr}]
1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano!