# Ugly matrices to fix

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, matrices

I'm having difficulties in setting four square matrices, one on top of each other.  They need to have the same size, i.e the same width for aesthetical reasons.  Currently,they are very ugly, as shown with this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \gamma^0 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \tensor{\sigma}{_2} \\[1em]
        \tensor{\sigma}{_2} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^1 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3}
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^2 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \tensor{\sigma}{_2} \\[1em]
        -\, \tensor{\sigma}{_2} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^3 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        i \tensor{\sigma}{_1} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & i \tensor{\sigma}{_1}
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

The minus signs are the source of the main trouble.  I tried using `\mathclap` around each element (except the 0), and adding some phantom terms to equalize the spacing, but it doesn't work very well and it feels very hacky.  So how can I make these matrices of the same size with well balanced elements inside?  I hate matrices in LaTeX!!

Comment: If you want the matrices to have the same size, there will probably be a lot of extraneous spaces.  Can you post an image of what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @L.F., I think the preview I gave above says it all.  Yes, some matrices will have some extra spaces, but it would look much better than the actual state.  The matrix $\gamma^1$ could have less middle space, to make some compromise.

Comment: Just to clarify, is that preview what you currently get or what you want to get?  An image of what you *want* to get probably helps, because there are many ways to place the elements with extra space.

Comment: How about [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522747)? MEOW! (Is this the Majorana representation? I also would typeset the `i` upright.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, yep, it's a Majorana representation!  By the way, what is your favorite Majorana rep, since there are many?

Comment: @Cham I do not use the Majorana representation, but prefer the chiral one.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, meow!  I too much prefer the chiral (Weyl) rep!  Purr purr!  Long live $\gamma^5$!  I love the Weyl equations!  Lets hope neutrinos have no mass at all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple code with `eqparbox`: I define an `\eqmathbox` command, which ensures that all math boxes sharing the same tag (`M` by default)  have the width of the largets natural width of their contents. It suffices to use this command with the widest element in each column (two compilations may be required).

Unrelated: needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`: the latter package does it for you.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \gamma^0 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \eqmathbox{\tensor{\sigma}{_2}} \\[1em]
       \eqmathbox{\tensor{\sigma}{_2} }& 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\[0.5ex]
    \gamma^1 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
       \eqmathbox{-i\tensor{\sigma}{_3}} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \eqmathbox{-i\tensor{\sigma}{_3}}
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\[0.5ex]
    \gamma^2 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \eqmathbox{\tensor{\sigma}{_2}} \\[1em]
        \eqmathbox{-\tensor{\sigma}{_2}} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\[0.5ex]
    \gamma^3 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
       \eqmathbox{i\tensor{\sigma}{_1}} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \eqmathbox{i\tensor{\sigma}{_1}}
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your \eqmathbox command.  Could you elaborate more on what it's doing?  How the matrices could get the same width?  This is like magic to me!  And is there any conflict between that eqparbox package and others (since I have many in my full doc)?

Comment: The matrices have the same width because each column of the matrices have the same width. Actually I use `\eqmakebox`  in which the contents is in math mode. As you know, the basic `\makebox` has a centred contents by default, so the elements in a column will be centred w.r.t. each other, i.e. will be centred in their column. If necessary you can use different tages for each column. For possible conflicts, I can see none

Comment: How would you get the same result without eqparbox?  Is this equivalent to using \mathclap and adding some phantom spaces?

Comment: Probably, except the code is simpler: you have to add a lot of `\phantom`s, and not forget a single one. Here, LaTeX measures all widths you tell it to measure and chooses the largest one (possibly in its column).

Comment: What I don't understand is how the code makes all the matrices have the same final width.  Is the command global for the whole document, or for that \align environment?

Comment: The width of a column is set by the tag used for `\eqmathbox` . As the tag is the same (the default `M`) for all columns of all matrices, these matrices will all have the same total width. Isn't it clear?

Comment: What is the M tag?  Is this an option from the package?

Comment: Not at  all: it's the way `eqparbox` works. Each  `eqparbox, \eqmakebox`, &c., uses a tag.The way it works is that all \eqparboxes with the same tag have the same width, namely the natural width of the  widest contents with this tag. In the case of `\eqmakebox`, this tag is specified between brackets because the standard `\makebox`  command specifies its width between brackets. For `eqparbox`, it would be between braces, like the standard `\parbox`. Please see the documentation of the package for more details.

Comment: I think I'm adopting your solution.

Comment: Thanks! I nevertheless recommend updating your distribution – many things have changed since 2015 (not sure there was a `nicematrix` package at that time).

Comment: @Cham: note that **two** compilations are required because the package `eqparbox` uses the `.aux` file to determine the optimal width of each group of tagged boxes.

Answer (score 17):

The package `nicematrix` has a feature dedicated to that problem. In an environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}`, all the matrices created by `nicematrix` (with `{bNiceMatrix}` but this environment will create the same result as `{bmatrix}` would do) will have the same width of columns. Two compilations are necessary.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
    \gamma^0 &=
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        0 & \tensor{\sigma}{_2} \\[1em]
        \tensor{\sigma}{_2} & 0
    \end{bNiceMatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^1 &=
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3}
    \end{bNiceMatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^2 &=
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        0 & \tensor{\sigma}{_2} \\[1em]
        -\, \tensor{\sigma}{_2} & 0
    \end{bNiceMatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^3 &=
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        i \tensor{\sigma}{_1} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & i \tensor{\sigma}{_1}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}.
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: Feels pretty cool!  Now wondering which solution is best, between Bernard's and yours.

Comment: It depends whether we think we may have to use the other features provided by `nicematrix`: continuous dotted lines, border matrices, use of the tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`...

Comment: I checked the documentation of nicematrix .  I'm now facing a big problem:  This package may revolutionize all my matrices, in a major HUGE document, and this means a lot of work.  Grrr!

Comment: Great as usual....:-) your package is very nice!

Comment: Darn!  Your code produces an emergency stop: "LaTeX Error: File `nicematrix.sty' not found."  Apparently, this package isn't included in my 2015 LaTeX distribution.  Maybe I should upgrade...

Comment: @Cham: Yes, `nicematrix` is a recent package which uses the most recent versions of `expl3`, `xparse` and `array`.

Comment: @Cham: If you want to use `nicematrix` for the continuous dotted lines, you won't have a lot of work: you only have to set `\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}` and the dotted lines in all `{pmatrix}`, `{bmatrix}`, `{vmatrix}` etc. will be changed automatically without any other change in the geometry of the ouput. On the other side, you can use the environments of `amsmath` (`{pmatrix}`, etc.) and of `nicematrix` (`{pNiceMatrix}`) in the same document...

Comment: When I upgrade my LaTeX version, I may adopt the nicematrix package since I have lots of matrices with dotted lines, and also continuous lines (from relativity theory, to separate the timelike and spacelike parts).  I always had troubles in setting my matrices in LaTeX before, so this package could be very helpfull!

Answer (score 4):

Post suggested by Schrödinger's cat's takes care of 'minus' for such spacings, but your matrices have lots of other factors which will need too many if conditions. Best way I found was to add phantom characters and produce the output. I am sure there will be a way to automate this, but if you just want it for three equations, adding `phantom` manually would serve the purpose.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \gamma^0 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \phantom{-}\tensor{\sigma}{_2}\phantom{3} \\[1em]
        \phantom{-}\tensor{\sigma}{_2}\phantom{3} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^1 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & -\, i \tensor{\sigma}{_3}
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^2 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \phantom{-}\tensor{\sigma}{_2}\phantom{3} \\[1em]
        -\, \tensor{\sigma}{_2}\phantom{3} & \phantom{-}0\phantom{3}
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    \gamma^3 &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{- }i \tensor{\sigma}{_1} & \phantom{-} 0 \phantom{3} \\[1em]
        0 & \phantom{-1}i\tensor{\sigma}{_1}
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: The matrices don't have exactly the same width.  And why the \phantom{3}?

Comment: @Cham I guess the answerer hoped that \phantom{3} would be the same width as i, but it isn't.

Comment: @alephzero yes. I personally feel the answers which automate this space are better than mine. I just tried to hack the problem, but the solutions suggested by other users look better.

Answer (score 0):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tikz}


  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    $ \gamma^0 =$ &{$\left[
      \begin{tabular}{p{0.75cm}p{0.75cm}}
       0 & $ \sigma _{2} $\\[1em]
       $ \sigma _{2}$ & 0
      \end{tabular}\right]$}
   \end{tabular}\\
        \vspace{1cm}

   \begin{tabular}{cc}
   $ \gamma^1 =$ & {$\left[
      \begin{tabular}{p{0.75cm}p{0.75cm}}
         $ -\iota \sigma_{3}$ & 0 \\[1em]
         0 & $-\iota \sigma_ {3}$
      \end{tabular}\right]$}
   \end{tabular}  
        \vspace{1cm}  

   \begin{tabular}{cc}
       $ \gamma^2 =$ &{$\left[
       \begin{tabular}{p{0.75cm}p{0.75cm}}
        0 & $\sigma_{ 2}$ \\[1em]
        $-\iota \sigma _2$ & 0
       \end{tabular}\right]$}
   \end{tabular}
         \vspace{1cm}

   \begin{tabular}{cc}    
     $ \gamma^3 =$& {$\left[
     \begin{tabular}{p{0.75cm}p{0.75cm}}   
         $ \iota \sigma _{1}$ & 0 \\[1em]
         0 & $ \iota \sigma_{1}$
     \end{tabular}\right]$}
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

Here I have used simple latex commands. I have proper latex terms e.g \iota for i. There is a correction in sigma also. I have tries to adjust the tabular columns also.

Comment: What's wrong with my sigma's ?  And I don't agree with iota for the complex "i".

Comment: There is nothing wrong. But simple notations are easy to correct. The notation I used are standard latex notations. i can not be iota. Please check with your own hand written documents. The notations are used to create  packages which are useful informatting books are in Journal articles. These are useful only we use repeated application.