# A macro has a pesky global effect when used in several environments

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, amsmath, matrices

I was using a cool macro to write some nice matrices inside a particular math environment, from this question:

[Ugly matrices to fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532283/ugly-matrices-to-fix/532306#532306)

But then I wanted to use the same macro to fix some other matrices which have nothing to do with the ones in the previous question (in another chapter of the same document).  I just noticed that the macro gives the same column spacings for all matrices, even when they aren't in the same environment.  The macro appears to have a global effect, which I certainly don't want.

How can I make that macro to work locally only, in a given environment, without having any affect on other environments?

Here's a MWE which shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\squash}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

These matrices are affected by the last matrices, which is bad:
\begin{align}
    A &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash{\sigma_2} \\[1em]
        \squash{\sigma_2}& 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    B &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash{-i \sigma_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash{-i \sigma_3}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
These matrices are affecting the first matrices which is bad:
\begin{align}
    C &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash{1} \\[1em]
        \squash{r \sin \vartheta \cos \varphi} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    D &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash{-\, r^2} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash{-\, r^2}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview with the problem shown in red:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `\squash` is wrong, in the sense that it doesn't make clear that the optional argument is actually mandatory.

The syntax of `\eqmakebox` is

```
\eqmakebox[<tag>][<alignment>]{<material>}
```

where the `<tag>` is an arbitrary label that should be common to all constructs that need to have the same width.

Since you're using `\squash` in different contexts, but never use the optional argument, you get the same width for all such boxes throughout the document.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\squash}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

These matrices are affected by the last matrices, which is bad:
\begin{align}
    A &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash[A]{\sigma_2} \\[1em]
        \squash[A]{\sigma_2}& 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    B &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash[A]{-i \sigma_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash[A]{-i \sigma_3}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
These matrices are affecting the first matrices which is bad:
\begin{align}
    C &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash[B]{1} \\[1em]
        \squash[B]{r \sin \vartheta \cos \varphi} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    D &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash[B]{-\, r^2} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash[B]{-\, r^2}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd make the argument mandatory and add an optional argument for the alignment, for greater flexibility:

```
\newcommand{\squash}[3][c]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$#3$}}
```

The calls in the document should become like

```
\squash{A}{\sigma_2}
```

Full code

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\squash}[3][c]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$#3$}}

\begin{document}

These matrices are affected by the last matrices, which is bad:
\begin{align}
    A &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash{A}{\sigma_2} \\[1em]
        \squash{A}{\sigma_2}& 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    B &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash{A}{-i \sigma_3} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash{A}{-i \sigma_3}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
These matrices are affecting the first matrices which is bad:
\begin{align}
    C &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \squash{B}{1} \\[1em]
        \squash{B}{r \sin \vartheta \cos \varphi} & 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \\
    D &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \squash{B}{-\, r^2} & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & \squash{B}{-\, r^2}
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\squash` should be a letter from `lcr` (meaning “left”, “center” and “right”, default is `c`).

Just by way of example, if you change all `\squash{A}{...}` into `\squash[l]{A}{...}` and all `\squash{B}{...}` into `\squash[r]{B}{...}`, you get

[image]

Not really useful in the present case, but you might find it useful in other circumstances.

Comment: Your last suggestion doesn't work, I don't know why.  You're missing a bracket } but it's still not working.

Comment: @Cham Yes, sorry: a `}` was missing

Comment: @Cham I added a full example

Comment: It appears to work great now.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you show an example for the optional argument (alignment?), to show some differences?

Comment: @Cham Added the example

Comment: Great!  By the way, your number of medals and reputation points are really impressive!