# Set \phantom{-} for all columns of a matrix that has at least one negative entry

Tags: matrices, phantom

I would like to add `\phantom{-}` to every column of a matrix that contains at least one entry with a `-` in front. [Here is an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522732) that my current code is based off. It inserts `\phantom{-}` in front of *every* entry that isn't negative, but that's not really what I am looking for.

My current attempt is attached below. Notice how in an array without negatives, it inserts phantoms in front of each entry, increasing the overall width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 12345 \\
        5 & 2 & 5     \\
        0 & 1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\]

% code that inserts \phantom{-}
\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix[#1]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\@tfor\@temp:=\matrix\pmatrix\bmatrix\Bmatrix\vmatrix\Vmatrix\do
{\expandafter\patchcmd\@temp
{\env@matrix}
{\@ifnextchar[
\env@matrix{\env@matrix[C]}}
{}{\FAILED}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\CheckSign}c}
\def\CheckSign\ignorespaces{%
\@ifnextchar-{}{\@ifnextchar+{}{\phantom{-}}}}
\makeatother

\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 12345 \\
        5 & 2 & 5     \\
        0 & 1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my working example:]

Comment: I would use right aligned columns, then the numbers are aligned on decimal places and the minus signs will automatically sort themselves out (`mathtools` package provides a variant of `bmatrix` where you can specify the alignment)

Comment: I'm not sure you really want this: if a column contains, say `12`, `-2` and `1`, adding the phantom `-` to the top entry would be too much.

Comment: @egreg That's a good point. What would you recommend to align negative numbers then? Would right aligned columns like David suggested be better than phantoms?