# What LaTeX macros cannot accept a group as an argument?

Tags: macros, grouping, parsing

I am working on a LaTeX pretty printer that parses a LaTeX document and then re-renders the source. (I know that this is not possible in all cases, but it should be possible a lot of the time.)

In the spirit of [Prettier](https://prettier.io), I want the code formatter to be opinionated, and I am trying to decide which macros should have their arguments automatically wrapped in a group {}. For example, `\mathbb R` should be converted to `\mathbb{R}`, and `\frac23` should be converted to `\frac{2}{3}`.

My question is: (a) Are there LaTeX macros where passing in a group will cause unexpected behavior? and (b) are there macros where it is considered "best practice" not to wrap the arguments in a group?

A follow-up question would be: what would you put on a list of "special" macros that are commonly used. This can include LaTeX macros that don't follow standard conventions (of `[...]` and `{...}` style arguments), or commonly-used macros that would need special handling (like almost everything in a *tikz* environment...).

To rein in the scope, I am **not** trying to parse complicated TeX programming or macro definitions themselves.

Comment: It depends what you call a macro. For instance, `\sffamily` should be used as is, and not e.g. like `\sffamily{text}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Good point. I mean a macro that accepts arguments.

Comment: It really depends on what you call a macro `$\left(1\right)$` works but `$\left{(}1\right{)}$` doesn't.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` are exactly the types of exceptions I'm looking for. I have no idea how they work, but I would imagine the macro is something like `\left(#1\right)`? And so the "argument" is really what's between the two...

Comment: all macros accept brace groups but not all commands are macros

Comment: You use the term "LaTeX macros" in the title of your query. Are you interested in LaTeX *macros* only, or are you willing to consider PlainTeX macros and TeX primitives as well? (Aside: `\left` and `\right` are primitives, not macros.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, to what should \frac234 be converted?

Comment: I might add that groups get parsed as single tokens unless you use \futurelet to handle them.

Comment: With macros that process brace-delimited arguments (`#{`-notation) wrapping a single token before the delimiting brace into braces will cause problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

All TeX macros take brace groups around their arguments, which may be omitted if the argument is a single token, although in the case of delimited arguments that group may not be where you mean.

```
\def\foo#1#2{...}
```

then `\foo12`, `\foo 1 2`, `\foo{1}{2}`, `\foo{1} {2}` are all equivalent.

```
\def\foo(#1,#2){...}
```

then `\foo(1,2)`, `\foo({1},{2})`, `\foo(1,{2})`,  are all equivalent.

---

TeX primitives do not have optional braces in this way.

`\hbox{a}`  the braces are mandatory `\hbox a`  is a syntax error, however the brace can be implicit `\hbox\bgroup a}` is OK.

`\hskip 5pt`  takes no braces, `\hskip{5pt}` is a syntax error

`\def\foo{zzz}`  must have no brace around the token being defined,

---

Some commands documented as taking arguments do not, so for example `\section` is a macro which takes no arguments it just looks ahead for `*` or `[` calling appropriate macros in each case, so

`\section*[short]{l}`  could be written as `\section*[{short}] l` but not `\section{*}[short]{l}`

---

Some packages redefine `^` and `_` to be macros and take arguments with optional brace groups as above, but the primitive behaviour is "interesting" as tex expands looking for possibly implicit braces so for example `x^\mathrm x`  is `x^{\mathrm{x}}` and `x^\frac12` is `x^{\frac{1}{2}}`  as the first level expansions of `\mathrm` and `\frac` provide the `{}` group needed for the superscript.

Comment: @UlrichDiez ooh yes thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer but anything that uses `\@ifnextchar` can cause problems. I borrowed `\CheckMinus` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174359).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\CheckMinus{\@ifnextchar-{got a minus}{no minus}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\left(1\right)$ % works
%$\left{(}1\right{)}$ % doesn't work

\CheckMinus-

\CheckMinus{-}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few TeX "primitives" take arguments that must not be delimited in a group.

- Text-mode and math-mode kerning commands: `\kern` and `\mkern`, which take 1 argument each.

  ```
  a\kern1em a
  $a\mkern18mu a$
  ```

  are both ok, but `a\kern{1em} a` and `$a\mkern{18mu} a$` are not.
- The commands `\raise` and `\lower`, which take 2 arguments each, the first of which must be a length variable and the second of which must be a (TeX) box.

  ```
  a\raise1ex\hbox{c}
  ```

  is ok, but `a\raise{1ex}\hbox{c}`, `a\raise1ex{\hbox{c}}`, and `a\raise{1ex}{\hbox{c}}` are not.

  The LaTeX counterpart to `a\raise1ex\hbox{c}` is `\raisebox{1ex}{c}`, which also takes two arguments. Clearly, with `\raisebox` is allowed -- and, depending on the arguments, may in fact be required.

Answer (score 3):

Problems will occur with macros whose last argument is delimited by an opening curly brace.
You can define such macros using the `#{`-notation with the `⟨parameter text⟩` of their definition.

An example of such a macro is the `\name`-macro.

The `\name`-macro is used for avoiding `\expandafter`-orgies with `\csname..\endcsname`.

The `\name`-macro processes an argument that is delimited by an opening curly brace.

It is defined as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother
```

It is used as follows:

`\name⟨stuff without curly braces⟩{macroname}`
→ `⟨stuff without curly braces⟩\macroname`

E.g.,

`\name{macro}` → `\macro`
`\name\newcommand{macro}...` → `\newcommand\macro...`
`\name\global\long\def{macro}...` → `\global\long\def\macro...`
`\name\string{macro}` → `\string\macro`
`\name\meaning{macro}` → `\meaning\macro`
`\name\name\global\let{macroA}={macroB}` → `\name\global\let\macroA={macroB}` → `\global\let\macroA=\macroB`

Assume `⟨stuff without curly braces⟩` is a single token, something like this:

`\name X{Y}` → `X\Y`

Further assume that your pretty printer wraps the `X` in a brace-group. In this case you have:

`\name {X}{Y}` → `\X{Y}`

, which is slightly different.

---

When TeX is searching for the tokens that form the delimiter of a delimited macro argument, it will not take things for an argument-delimiter that are nested in a brace-group other than the brace-group wherein the macro in question is nested.

Assume a macro's argument is delimited by the character `a`:

```
\def\macro#1a{This is the argument: (#1)}
```

The sequence

```
\macro aa
```

yields:

```
This is the argument: ()a
```

Assume the pretty-printer wraps the first `a` into curly braces:

The sequence

```
\macro{a}a
```

yields:

```
This is the argument: (a)
```

, which is slightly different.