# tex equivalent of Excel's conditional formatting

Tags: tables, excel

Has anyone implemented (either through hacky own scripts or an actual package) something that emulates Excel's conditional formatting?

It would be useful to have the ability to colour the contents of a table cell proportionally to their value to easily visualise trends at a glance.

Google hasn't helped me a great deal here, so either "conditional formatting" doesn't mean much in the TeX world and I'm failing to find anything, or its as difficult as I'm suspecting it might be.

Anyone have any information?

Comment: I think we had some questions about colouring of table cells depending on values ...

Comment: Related/duplicates? [LaTeX Tables: Cell value color based on its sign / conditional cell color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174234/2693), [Automatic coloring of numbers according to size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57334/2693) and possibly most helpful: [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44868/2693)

Comment: I found the thread about colouring based on sign, but that relied on physically checking that the number has a '-' and I was looking for something that'd colour by relative magnitudes

Comment: `collcell` package looks like it might be a winner however!

Comment: @JoeHealey If you think the second link I posted is answers your question we can close your question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I haven't had chance to test it yet but I think yes this can be closed as a dupe of that link. It looks promising.