# \cellcolor involving calculation

Tags: color

In a table, I would like to color the cell with a given scheme, as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\ccra[1]{\FPeval{\result}{50*#1}\cellcolor{red!{\result}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\ccra{0.9} & \ccra{1.1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can this be properly achieved?

Even with the `pgf` package, the following definition fails

```
\newcommand{\ccra}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{10.0*(#1)}
    \cellcolor{red!\pgfmathresult}
}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/automatic-coloring-of-numbers-according-to-size

Comment: @Marijn Interesting link but what I have in mind is a use of `\cellcolor` command which causes difficulties even with the `pgf` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commented code works if you prefer a Ti*k*Z/PGF solution; the uncommented code if you prefer `fp`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\ccra[1]{\FPeval\result{50*#1}\xdef\tempa{\result}\cellcolor{red!\tempa}}
% \newcommand{\ccra}[1]{%
%   \pgfmathparse{10.0*(#1)}\xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}%
%   \cellcolor{red!\tempa}%
% }
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\ccra{0.9} & \ccra{1.1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: shades of red]

The error with your original code tells you that `\result` is no longer defined by the time `\cellcolor` tries to use it. Hence, we use a global definition.