# Change font colour in cell based on min and max thresholds

Tags: tables, color

I have been trying various methods to change the text colour of the cells in a table that I use based on thresholds (-2, 2).

[Automatic coloring of numbers according to size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/automatic-coloring-of-numbers-according-to-size)

I followed the instructions from the link above but I cannot add both of the thresholds.
The table that I want to apply the function comes as an input to the main latex document.

```
\documentclass{report}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx} % Library for images and graphs
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Change page orientation
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[textwidth=18cm,textheight=25cm]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{rotating} % Rotating images
\usepackage{hyperref}
% The bellow are for colouring the numbers in a table
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\bordervalue}{-2}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{int(less(#1,\bordervalue))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
       \color{red} #1
    \else
       \color{green!60!black} #1
    \fi
}
\newcolumntype{l}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

% Start document
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{6cm}{\input{"F:/monitoring/Output/Data/table.tex"}}
\caption{} 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

The table's actual form is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
\toprule
Column & Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5 & Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5 \\
\midrule
ROW1 & 0.580741 & 0.580741 & 0.580741 & 0.668614 & 0.819488 & -1.20926 & -1.20926 & -1.78011 & -1.20926 & -1.20926 \\
ROW2 & 0.560995 & 0.560995 & 1.00685 & 0.560995 & 0.577672 & -0.414748 & -0.981595 & -3.42207 & -0.556372 & -0.728903 \\
Statistics & Max & Max & Max & Max & Max & Min & Min & Min & Min & Min \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

How can I add a command to take account both values? (-2 and 2)
Because right now I only change the colour on the numbers that are bellow -2. I would like the same for numbers greater than 2.

Comment: BTW: you should make this into a single document, the resizing is not related to your problem and it is easier for others whn the only have to copy and test a single document

Comment: Your code works just fine, but `Column1` is not a number, neither is `Max`. So the text entries should be wrapped in something like `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` to keep them away from processing. Also you probably don't want to overwrite an existing column type, I renamed it A instead. I'd also apply `\num` from `siunitx` or plain math mode in `#1` in `\ApplyGradient` for format the negatice numbers correctly