# Apply collcell to only some of the tables in my document

Tags: tables, collcell

I'd like to use the method shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/automatic-coloring-of-numbers-according-to-size) to color only *some* of the tables in my document. How can I specify which tables should be colored using collcell and which shouldn't?

In addition, I would like to have different min/max values for each table.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the columntype you defined only for those tables you want to be affected.

Comment: To make the comment by Skillmon concrete: for colored tables, use `\begin{tabular}{R R R R R}` (of course adapted to your specific number of columns) and for noncolored tables use `\begin{tabular}{r r r r r}` (standard right-aligned columns). For the min/max values you can use `\renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.3}%` and similar for the max value just before you start the table.

Comment: Ok thanks! That makes sense!